# Datagrid using ajax to save and delete

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datagrid

I created grid using `javascript` and I am using ajax to get data to save in database and there's a `next-prev` in the  grid its take just the first page data when I click save

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../test/delete_remove_fromGrid.php", 

    data: $("form_name").serialize(),

    success: function(data) {

    }//end success
```

Comment: There's no question here. Tell us what you expect and what the results are and then ask an explicit question.

Comment: okay! the grid is divided to multiple parts in the same page there's a next and previous buttons to moves between them and i used this code to get all the data from grid and save it , but it works with the first part of  grid only  not all parts ! the question is how can I get all the data from the table from all parts?

Comment: https://www.google.jo/search?q=grid&rlz=1C1VFKB_enJO600JO600&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=923&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWhIa-qYHKAhVBwxoKHR1dB94Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=grid+with+next+and+prev+data&imgrc=CMreKkxGxUNe5M%3A
the grid look like this and its editable thats whty I need to know how to save all changes !

Comment: I suggest you read some questions and answers on this site so that you'll understand how to put together a good question. Apparently your question deals with how to read the data from your table, yet you are showing the  code for posting to the database. Focus your code example on the question. But to give you a high level answer, you'll probably want to use JavaScript to initialize a datastructure while iterating over the HTML table.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to SO!

Comment: I think its hard to explain my question because I'm not good enough in English ! so thanks anyway